# How to write a wrapper class for a set of hardware registers

Tags: c++, hardware

I have a Cortex-M4 here with SPI hardware. The SPI supports different transfer formats which are defined in specific registers (`CTARn`). Which `CTAR` is used in a transfer is defined when writing data to the SPI buffer (`PUSHR`), using a set of bits in the value. A struct with these registers might look like this:

```
struct SPI_REGS
{
  volatile uint32_t PUSHR;
  volatile uint32_t CTAR0;
  volatile uint32_t CTAR1;
};
```

I want to write a templated class to use the SPI. One of the template arguments is the number of the CTAR that the class is allowed to use:

```
template<SPI_REGS* spi, uint8_t n>
class usesTheSpi
{
  usesTheSpi()
  {
    spi->CTAR[n] = someSettings;
  }
};
```

Accessing the CTARs using the subscript operator requires a class that provides it:

```
template<SPI_REGS* spi>
class CTARn
{
  volatile uint32_t& operator[](uint8_t n) {return ((volatile uint32_t*)spi->CTAR0)[n];}
};
```

The SPI class needs a member of type `CTARn` to provide this kind of access, but I can't figure out how to get it in there. I still want to use the plain registers as in `SPI.CTAR0 = 0`.

---

Edit: This is as close as I got. It compiles, but the second line in main() results in a segmentation fault:

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct SPI_HW_REGS
{
  volatile uint32_t CTAR0;
  volatile uint32_t CTAR1;
  volatile uint32_t PUSHR;
} __attribute__((packed));

template<SPI_HW_REGS* base>
class SPI : public SPI_HW_REGS
{
  class CTARn
  {
    public:
      volatile uint32_t& operator[](const uint8_t& i) const
      {
        return ((volatile uint32_t*)base->CTAR0)[i & 1];
      }
  };
  public:
    CTARn CTAR;
};

SPI_HW_REGS SPI0_REGS; // dummy set of memory mapped registers
SPI<&SPI0_REGS>& SPI0 = *((SPI<&SPI0_REGS>*)&SPI0_REGS);

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  SPI0.CTAR0 = 0x55;
  cout << "CTAR[0] = " << hex << "0x" << SPI0.CTAR[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I think it's how I use `base->CTAR0` to return the requested register, but I don't know how to work around that. I tested this only on my laptop. I don't know if it would result in an error on the actual hardware.

Comment: If the registers are memory mapped, you might want to use pointers initialized to point to the registers instead of ordinary values.

Comment: The registers are memory mapped, so yes, I can use pointers to access them and that's what I usually do when I know which registers to use. In this case, however, I want to create `usesTheSpi` in such a way that I can specify which register to use. It's not only the register's name that depends on this parameter.